# If humans lived on the moon, could they send a mission with the same goals as Apollo to the Earth?

Tags: apollo-program

The humans on the moon have similar technology to the humans (us) on Earth.

Comment: You wouldn’t need to do so. The moons escape velocity is much lower than on earth so if moonlings built a rocket that can fly to earth, it would be much smaller than the Saturn V.

Comment: This doesn't seem off-topic to me, it can certainly be answered. It's not a bad question from a new user.

Comment: This question is not off topic and it’s definitely not about weather.

Comment: This is certainly not about Psychis, Weather, or Astronomy. While it might be better for Worldbuilding, thats another story

Answer (score 15):

The moon has much lower gravity than the Earth, so sending something on a one-way trip would have been very easy, it's getting them back which would present a much bigger technical challenge than Apollo.

If the Moon people wanted to send a probe to the surface Earth they would need a small rocket to launch the probe to moon orbit, then a small amount of thrust to get it into Earth's gravity well. All it would need then is an ablative heat shield and a parachute to make a soft landing. Because they have less gravity to contend with they could make much bigger spacecraft as it's far easier to launch them.

It's when they want to come back that it becomes very challenging, because to get to orbit you need a large rocket due to Earth's much higher gravity. This means they would either have to soft-land a fully-fueled multi-stage rocket, which is an incredibly difficult thing to do even today, or they would have had to land the components separately (remember it's easier for them to send large payloads due to low moon gravity), assemble and fuel the rocket for the return to orbit on the surface of the Earth, which is still extremely hard but would have been at least theoretically possible with Apollo technology.

Comment: They would also have the advantage that a crewed mission is easier because the crew can live on the Earth's surface, and building a rocket for return is easier with a crew than without one.  In fact, the crew might discover that, apart from gravity, they prefer Earth to the Moon :-)

Comment: I wouldn't make that assumption, an organism adapted for the moon may have serious trouble surviving in 6x gravity.

Comment: The question says "**humans** on the moon", though.

Comment: It wasn't clear whether the poster meant actual humans on the moon or beings having developed on the moon.  If humans are born on the moon they may not develop the skeletal or muscular strength to survive back on earth. We just don't know. In any case it didn't seem to be in scope for the question.

Comment: If this were [Worldbuilding.SE], one could hypothesise a future in which humans have colonised both Earth and Moon, then lost the technology to move between them due to some catastrophe.  I agree that we don't know exactly what the OP has in mind, though.

Comment: I think they could have a 2 stage rocket/plane. The first stage would bring them to earths orbit (Which could be done very easily due to the escape velocity of the moon), then the would leave the first stage in LEO and land without using fuel with a space plane (Something like Skylon) and after that take off with the plane and dock with the first stage. Then the moonlings could return to moon using the first stage.